# How can I pull HTML data from a site that requires a button click?

Tags: javascript, html, cross-domain

I'm trying to write a script that will pull schedule information from a website by using Google Scripts. Using [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object)) I can retrieve the raw HTML string from the target URL and have it output it to the log.

```
function myFunction() {
var options ={
"validateHttpsCertificates" : false 
};
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.cnatra.navy.mil/scheds/schedule_data.aspx?sq=vt-31",options);
Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

The obstacle I'm facing is that once the page loads, the schedule won't appear until the *View Schedule* button is pressed. The button is a "submit" input. **Is there any way I can add a POST payload to my function to either simulate a button click or trigger the submit as the button would have? Or is it possible instead to pass the button click through a URL parameter?** [Here](https://www.cnatra.navy.mil/scheds/schedule_data.aspx?sq=vt-2) is the website.